# python3 command in Subprocess.Popen() not responding after converting python file to macOS executable

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, subprocess, py2app

Because my project is too big, this is a small example where you show the output of the command run on subprocess on tkinter. It works fine! But when I convert it to a macOS application it doesn't work and I think I have found out that error is happening in line where I call `subprocess.Popen()`. I am using `py2app` to convert my app to an executable so everyone can use it without installing python.

Below is my code for the tkinter application:

hello.py:

```
import subprocess
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

l = Label(root, text="hello")
l.pack()

process = subprocess.Popen(
    "python3 test.py",
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    shell=True
)

l.config(text=process.communicate()[0])
root.mainloop()
```

As you see I will run `test.py` in `subprocess.Popen()` which simply contains `print("Hello World")`

Below is `setup.py` where I use `py2app` and `setuptools` to convert `hello.py` into a macOS application:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['hello.py']
DATA_FILES = ['test.py']
OPTIONS = {}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

The Problem is that it doesn't work only as an executable file. However, this problem is too broad. So I experimented with my code and checked which line is causing it. I found out `subprocess.Popen()` line is where it is causing that problem. Ok is it `subprocess.Popen()` that's causing the error? Well I tried to use basic terminal commands like `ls` and they worked fine. Now its very clear that command `python3` is where the problem is generating.

Please help me resolve this problem. I guess the `subprocess.Popen()` cannot access the python command when it is in the executable file. Is there a way for it access it even when its converted to macOS application?

**EDIT!!!:**

I FOUND THE ERROR! How can I not think about stderr! I tried displaying `stderr`(do this: `l.config(text=process.communicate()[1])`) on the tkinter window it shows this:

```
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x000000010096c580 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

Please help me resolve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try starting the python executable directly, not using shell:

```py
In [10]: import sys, subprocess
    ...: 
    ...: def run_python(*args, inp: str = '', python: str = sys.executable):
    ...:     with subprocess.Popen(
    ...:         ((python,) + args),  # <- use the same interpreter executable
    ...:         shell=False,  # <- start it directly
    ...:         stdin=subprocess.PIPE,  # <- don't forget stdin
    ...:         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    ...:         stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    ...:     ) as proc:
    ...:         return proc.communicate(inp)
    ...: 
    ...: out, err = run_python('-c', 'print("Hello world!")')
    ...: print((out, err))
(b'Hello world!\n', b'')
```

Comment: I ran setup.py and getting this error `ImportError: No module named PyInstaller.hooks.hook-gi.repository.GstInsertBin`.

Comment: There was so problem with my directory so I changed it and it works